# Jquery - swipebox - problemas na visualização com os botões .close .prev . next

Tags: html, jquery, css

Desculpe por qualquer tipo de postagem errada, tags etc. Ser minha primeira postagem.

Olá, estou passando por um problema que não consigo resolver. Fiz uma galeria em swipebox. Fiz um arquivo de imagem chamado icons.png com os desenhos dos botões ( X    <  > ) e chamei ele no meu código. Os botões estão se repetindo ( está ficando X   X  X ) o que deveria ser as setinhas do lado direito. Alguém pode me ajudar porque está repetindo esses X sendo que no arquivo icons.png está desenhado corretamente? Muito obrigado.

Segue o trecho do meu arquivo swipebox.css (se quiserem inteiro eu mando) e o print da tela que está imprimindo.

```html
#swipebox-action #swipebox-prev,
#swipebox-action #swipebox-next,
#swipebox-action #swipebox-close {
  background-image: url(../images/icons.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
}

#swipebox-action #swipebox-close {
  background-position: 15px 12px 0 auto;
  left: 40px;
}

#swipebox-action #swipebox-prev {
  background-position: 15px 25px 0 auto;
  right: 100px;
}

#swipebox-action #swipebox-next {
  background-position: -38px 13px 0 auto;
  right: 40px;
}

#swipebox-action #swipebox-prev.disabled,
#swipebox-action #swipebox-next.disabled {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

[TELA] - notem que tem uns pontinhos também, parece bugado.
Estranho porque chamar uma imagem deveria aparecer exatamente a imagem.
Seria alguma configuração no meu swipebox.css que estaria repetindo esses X   X  X?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkJb7.png